Why does the partition function require an integral?
The partition function of a single particle can be given by:
$$Z_1 = \sum_{E_r}^{}e^{-\beta E_r}$$
Where $E_r$ denotes the energy of microstate $r$
But the energy of a particle is given by:
$$E_r = \frac{\textbf{p}^2}{2m}$$
So the parition function can be writen as:
$$Z_1 = \sum_{E_r}^{}e^{-\beta \frac{\textbf{p}^2}{2m}}$$
My lecture notes say it is necessary to convert the summation into an integral because momentum is continuous, so that you end up with the following:
$$Z_1 = \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}\int{d^3\textbf{p}d^3\textbf{x}e^{-\beta \frac{\textbf{p}^2}{2m}}}$$
I understand the methodology behind the preceding steps well, but my confusion arrises because I do not see why it is necessary to convert to an integral just because $\textbf{p}$ is continuous. Momentum is continuous, but each state will still have a well defined value of $\textbf{p}$, and for that matter $E_r$ is continuous anyway, so do this mean the partition function as it's generally presented:
$$Z_1 = \sum_{E_r}^{}e^{-\beta E_r}$$
is actually just wrong?

"I do not see why it is necessary to convert to an integral just because p is continuous." How are you going to "sum" over a continuous momentum variable then? The "$\sum_i$" symbol is used for discrete summations where $i$ takes on discrete values like 1, 2, 3, etc. Your momentum is your summation (integration) variable, and it takes on any real values, so it is not discrete, it is continuous.

Index $r$ is now the momentum, and there is infinite number of momenta, since it is continuous.

One way to look at it is the following: The sum is the correct representation for a regularized system with a countable Hilbert space (by e.g. working with periodic boundary conditions).
The continuous case is then retrieved as limit as you let your periodic boundary condition length scale go to infinity (and renormalizing the scale of $Z$, usually there is something like $1/V$ in the expression as it is infinite otherwise, even $\int dx$ alone diverges).
The approach of starting with the sum is really useful as it gives you a well behaved system to work with (while the uncountable case is full of pitfalls).

We are much better at doing integral than sum.  There is also a practical reason why we almost always turn the sum into an integral in analytical calculation...
